# vlookup with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have this below data set and earlier I was using this array formula {=VLOOKUP(B5,C1:J3,{5,6,7,8},FALSE)} to fetch the information from the table with the roll no.

Now I am trying to make this work with two criteria Roll no. and session but unable to do it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `A10`:

```
=INDEX(G2:J3,MATCH(1,INDEX((B2:B3=B6)*(C2:C3=B5),),0),0)
```

Or, with ms365:

```
=FILTER(G2:J3;(B2:B3=B6)*(C2:C3=B5);"")
```